# Patching a Rails application (Redmine) from plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redmine

I'm trying to write a validator plugin for Redmine 2.5.0 which is on Rails 3. The plugin is supposed to check some values of an `Issue` and prohibit updates in case conditions are not met. I have written the plugin code but somehow I can't make Redmine accept the changes I've made.

I have the following plugin project:

```
product_release_control
  |_ config
  |_ lib
  |  |_ patches
  |    |_ issues_patch.rb
  |_ init.rb
```

In my `isssues_patch.rb` I have the following code:

```
module ProductReleaseControl
  module IssuesPatch
    def self.included(base)
      base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)

      base.class_eval do
        unloadable

        validate :check_related_tasks
      end
    end

    module InstanceMethods
      def check_related_tasks
        Rails.logger.info "**** INSIDE PRODUCT RELEASE PATCH METHOD"
        #code here
      end
    end 
  end
end

ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do
    Issue.send(:include, ProductReleaseControl::IssuesPatch)
end
```

and `init.rb` is as follows:

```
#encoding: utf-8
require 'patches/issues_patch'

Redmine::Plugin.register :product_release_control do
    name 'Product Release Control plugin'
    author 'Author name'
    description '...'
    version '0.0.1'
end
```

The problem is that after I execute `rake redmine:plugins:migrate` and reload apache, I can't see any changes. When I run `Issue.included_modules` I don't see my module in the list.

I also tried to move ActionDispatch part to init.rb, but this gives me `Uninitilized constant ProductReleaseControl`. So how do I include my patch in Redmine?

Comment: For previous Redmine versions I wrote `Rails.configuration.to_prepare` See [example](https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_time_limit/blob/master/lib/redmine_time_limit.rb#L11)

Comment: @gotva, that is supposed to work for Rails2 and my version of Redmine is on Rails3 where it should be `ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do`

Comment: The given example works fro Redmine 2.2 (it is 3rd Rails). But I checked some redmine tutorials and I see that they suggest just send patch if module has not been included yet. Look at this [article](http://www.redmine.org/boards/3/topics/31445#Overriding-models-controllers-and-helpers) (code for `boards_watchers_patches.rb`)